# Alternatives not working well for Java installation on Centos 6.4

Tags: centos, java

I am trying to installing on Centos java from Oracle. Following are my steps.

```
yum install /usr/local/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.rpm


alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java 20000

alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/javaws 20000

alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 20000

alternatives --config java I pick the latest version here.
```

The problem now only my java is pointing to the new version wheras the javac is not pointing to it below is how I trace for java and javac.

Java

```
 ls -la /usr/bin/java lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 May 22 13:09 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

 ls -la /etc/alternatives/java lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 May 22 13:09 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/java/latest/bin/java
```

Javac

```
ls -la /usr/bin/javac lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23 May 22 11:37 /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac

 ls -la /etc/alternatives/javac lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 48 May 22 11:37 /etc/alternatives/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac
```

Any solution to overcome this? I have tried previously on other machines on Centos 6.3 works fines.

Comment: `alternatives --config javac`

Comment: ok so wat should I do just the right one is it? But why this did not work alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 20000

Comment: That installs a new alternative, it does not set it as the current selected alternative.

Comment: Ok I will try and update you on this. Thank you.

Comment: Great it is working well now. So should I make sure each time I install java to pick to set both java and javac? I would like to confirm the rest of the steps are they ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See 'air-dex' example on this post:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk .  Note: sometimes people install Java JDK's into '/usr/lib/jvm', and as you can see in the output on my blog post, the system came with default JVMs in this location, but personally I don't recommend that for a JDK.  Maybe I would choose '/usr/lib/jvm' if it was a JRE I was installing.  If you wanted an alternative location for JDKs and JREs, I would choose either:

```
   1. /usr/java/
   2. /opt/java/
```

If I were comparing to windows, I might say:

```
JDKs: /usr/java = C:\Java
JREs: /usr/lib/jvm = C:\Program Files\Java
Alt:  /opt/java = E:\Java
```

Comment: I saw your blog but you are using rpm I used yum install is that better ?  So I should config both java and javac right. How about the alternatives should I still set them?

Comment: There is a "alternatives-java" command that you can use (instead of plain 'alternatives') that might be capable of updating all the symlinks for all the programs within a particular JDK.  I've not tried it yet.   Using rpm, Yum, or whatever, the install location may vary depending on the opinion of the person who made the installer.  I always prefer .bin (or .zip) archives because you can unzip them to wherever you want and you can be more intentional about it.

Comment: The blog post link is broken.